# How can I set the rest of width to an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
input, div{
  border:1px solid;
  margin: 20px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<input />
<div>
something
</div>
```

All I want to do is making the `input` the same width as the `div`.

Noted that neither `display: block;` nor `width: 100%;` won't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on parent element or in this case `body` and flexbox will make both items same width by default if you use `flex-direction: column`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
input, div{
  border:1px solid;
  margin: 20px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div>
something
</div>
```

Or you can use `calc` and hardcode width - margin to input element.

```css
input, div{
  border:1px solid;
  margin: 20px 30px 0px 30px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div>
something
</div>
```

Or you can add a wrapper and set the `margin` property *(or even `padding`)* to it:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 20px 30px 0px 30px;
}

.input_wrapper {
  margin: 20px 30px 0px 30px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_wrapper">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
  something
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah the output is correct. Thank you, upvote But I cannot use this approaches, because both `flex` and `calc` are CSS3, which I don't want that.

Comment: How about jquery then?

Comment: I guess using jQuery is the only option I can do. Isn't there any pure CSS way?

Comment: Can you use `padding` on body instead of margin https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1882/

Answer (score 0):

You could try `object-fit: fill;`

see this [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit?v=example)

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you do it entirely 100% and add a border to it, it will go above 100%. What you can do is add border inset as below :

```
<input />
<div>
something
</div>

input, div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

See here : https://jsfiddle.net/b5yguuaw/1/